# Linux, mapping multiple DMA addresses to a single virtual address

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, dma, pci

I have a number of memory pointers, allocated by dma_pool_alloc. For all of them, I have DMA bus address (dma_addr_t), kernel virtual address (void*), and length. I have no problems addressing them as a single entity via read/write operations provided by character device, but this approach slows down speed pretty hard (many kernel calls). I would like to map them all to a single virtual address in userspace. Stuff like remap_pfn_range accepts only a single address, which doesn't really cut it. Is there a way to do it?

P.S. Yeah, there is a number of similar questions here on SO, but none of them refer to mapping more than a single physical address.

Comment: All of them to a single address? At different times I guess?

Comment: No, not really. I need something like what vmalloc provides - multiple physical addresses bound to a single virtual memory chunk.

Comment: @margaret-bloom Thing is, userspace application is ported from Windows, and Windows driver did that by allocating whole required space at boot time. Application works with a single pointer to the data. Would do that by using CMA, but with the distribution we use, there are some restrictions - kernel is built without it, and due to private process of kernel compilation in this stupid distro, I can't rebuild it myself. AFAIK, they force it because allowing users to rebuild kernel would destroy some of the government certifications...

Comment: `vmalloc` alloc maps multiple physical maps to a single virtual address **range**. Didi you mean to map physical discontinuous ranges into a virtually continuous range? The mapping is a *function*, you can have multiple physical addresses Pi for the same virtual address V at the same time.

Comment: Yes, mapping physical discontinuous ranges into a virtually continuous range is exactly what I want, along with a way to introduce this virtually continuous range to userspace. Thanks :) How do I do that with the data I have (in the question)?

Comment: Next problem is that dma_addr_t is not really a physical address, it is a bus address. virt_to_phys from virtual kernel address should work, right?

Comment: It’s called *scatter-gathered list*. That’s what is used for huge DMA transactions. Look at *scatterlist.h* for the details.